# Set button style in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xceed

How can I set the style of a Button? I use Xceed.wpf.toolkit

```
 Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox mbox = new Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox();
 System.Windows.Style style = new System.Windows.Style(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Button));
 style.Setters.Add( new System.Windows.Setter(System.Windows.Controls.Button.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.DarkGreen));
 mbox.OkButtonStyle = style;
```

I get the error

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''System.Drawing.SolidBrush' is not a valid value for the 'System.Windows.Documents.TextElement.Foreground' property on a Setter.'
```

Comment: Just because im interested: why not setting the style in WPF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be sure to use the WPF libraries and not the WindowsForms or GDI+ ones...

What you should use: `System.Windows.Media.Brushes` which contains `DarkGreen` as `System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush` (in PresentationCore.dll).

What you currently use is `System.Drawing.Brushes` and `System.Drawing.SolidBrush`.

Answer (score 2):

[`TextElement.Foreground` is of type `System.Windows.Media.Brush`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textelement.foreground(v=vs.110).aspx). That's it's "data type". You have to assign it a value of that type, or some subclass of that type.

`System.Drawing.Brushes.DarkGreen` is of type `System.Drawing.Brush`, which is not a subclass of `System.Windows.Media.Brushes`. That's from Windows Forms or something, not WPF. You need to use a WPF brush object for a WPF control.

Get rid of `using System.Drawing;` at the top of your C# file. In a WPF project, that'll cause you nothing but trouble. Use `System.Windows.Media.Brushes.DarkGreen` instead.

```
style.Setters.Add( new System.Windows.Setter(System.Windows.Controls.Button.ForegroundProperty, 
    System.Windows.Media.Brushes.DarkGreen));
```

You could also create the Style as a XAML resource and load it with `FindResource()`. Then you'd just say "DarkGreen" and let the XAML parser worry about what kind of brush to create:

```
<Style 
    x:Key="XCeedMBoxButtonStyle" 
    TargetType="{x:Type Button}" 
    BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"
    >
    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="DarkGreen" />
</Style>
```

C#

```
var style = FindResource("XCeedMBoxButtonStyle") as Style;
```

But then you've got to worry about defining it someplace where it can be found, and what you're doing will work OK anyhow if you just use the right Brush class.

It's pretty gruesome that we've got multiple classes called `Brush` in multiple .NET namespaces with uninformative names like "System.Windows.Media" vs "System.Drawing", but unfortunately it all just sort of grew that way.

Comment: Aw, you beat me by 8 seconds xD